# spark-java: Path exclusion in before filter

Tags: java, spark-java

I'm new to the spark-java framework and I was wondering if anyone has a good solution for checking if a user is authenticated.
If the user isn't authenticated, I want to redirect to "/login".
The best solution for this is in a before filter in my opinion. But then we have a redirect loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    before((req, res) -> {
        User usr = new User("DUMMY");
        if (!Authentication.isUserAuthenticated(usr)) {
            res.redirect("/login");
        }
    });
    get("/login", (req, res) -> {
        return "Sir, your credentials please!";
    });
    get("/", (req, res) -> {
        return "Welcome!";
    });
}
```

Is there any way to exclude a specific path? Or do you have any adivice for a better solution?

best regards,
Philipp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a better approach wold be halting with the http not authorized status instead of redirecting. You cold do so by replacing the redirection in your before filter with `halt(401)`. Then you should handle this status code in your client code. Are you using any framework for your client code, like AngularJs ?

Comment: This sounds good. Didn't thought about that. I want to use AngularJS, but haven't used it before. Need to check how to do that.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/cool-stuff/create-a-rest-services-layer-with-spark) to inspire your server side implementation. And for your client code, you can get the inspiration [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543) (I've used this tutorial when first time implementing an AngularJs Auth). Thanks to people who wrote both posts.

Comment: Thank you Laercio for your help / advice / recommendations.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I implement a login with AngularJS, I need to post the data. But then I also will run into the before filter. How you manage to avoid that or how can I then check the login credentials?

Comment: In my case there were public and protected resources. So I declared all the routes that requires the user to be authenticated under "/api/protected" and declared my filter like this `before("/api/protected/*", (request, response) -> {
    /* check if authenticated */
    halt(401, "Go Away!");
});`. Resources that don't require the user to be authenticaded, I declared under "/api/public".

Comment: That seems to work. I much appreciate your help! Thank you!